# How to change colour of a certain word in an HTML file in a Java code?

Tags: java, html

In the pre-existing code, the HTML file background colour has been set like this:

```
 file+="<table width=\"95%\" align=\"center\" style=\"background : #"+
                HTML_REPORT_COLOR_2+"; border : 1px solid #000000\">";

file+="Wrong colour for driver has been chosen . The correct tag is Green";
                file+="<br/><br/>";
```

I want to change the wrong word which is presently in black to red. The right way to go about using the fonts tag, but how do I use it here, as this is a Java code. I tried feeding it to the file variable, but "#" is giving me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Current

Wrap the word "Wrong" in a span tag, like this:

```
<span class="error">Wrong</span>
```

If you have access to the CSS of the document, add this declaration:

```
.error{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

If you don't have access to the CSS, make the `span` element look like this, instead:

```
<span style="color: #FF0000;">Wrong</span>
```

### Previous

If I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to do, you need to change the hexadecimal value of `HTML_REPORT_COLOR_2` from `000000` or `000` to `FF0000` or `F00`.

That should be the solution, unless I'm mis-understanding your problem.

Comment: The thing is the first line of code is an example of how the actual coders have done it . I am failing to do it here for the word WRONG .

Comment: nitpick suggestion: use a class name of .wrong instead of .red. If you use 'red' odds are at some point, someone will want it to be purple instead, and then the HTML begins to get rather confusing.

Comment: The error that I am getting is : expected ; Illegal character : \35 not a statement .

Comment: file+="<span style="color: #FF0000;">Wrong</span>"; I did this . And there is no access to the css file

Comment: You need to escape your quotes.  So it would be: file+="<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\">Wrong</span>";